# How to retrieve object from input value?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this input field

```
<input type="hidden" class="tax_obj" value="[{" taxid":1,"taxname":"vat","taxpercentage":13,"sortorder":1,"calculationmode":null},{"taxid":2,"taxname":"hst","taxpercentage":10,"sortorder":2,"calculationmode":null}]">
```

How can I retrieve this object in javascript?

Comment: Check your syntax highlighting, you have to escape the quotes inside your value. Or use `'` (like `value='..."...'` ) . Then you can get the value by simply accessing the value property: `console.log(document.querySelector('.tax_obj').value)` 
`

Comment: @cloned There's no escaping in HTML attributes.

Comment: I thought that this is possible, but I didn't try it. I would have used `'` instead anyways. Good to know, thanks. Maybe I will remember it this time. Thanks @Barmar

Comment: Why are you putting JSON in a hidden input in the first place, only to retrieve it later? Can you tell us what problem you're trying to solve by storing JSON in an input? As opposed to, say, `localStorage`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use single quotes around the value, so the delimiter doesn't conflict with the quotes in the JSON.

```
<input type="hidden" class="tax_obj" value='[{" taxid":1,"taxname":"vat","taxpercentage":13,"sortorder":1,"calculationmode":null},{"taxid":2,"taxname":"hst","taxpercentage":10,"sortorder":2,"calculationmode":null}]'>
```

Then you can use `JSON.parse()` to parse the value.

```
let value = JSON.parse(document.querySelector(".tax_obj").value);
```

Comment: I am dynamically assigning object to input field. How can I use single quotes in there?? Double quotes is coming by default...

Comment: You don't need to worry about quotes when assigning dynamically, only when writing HTML.

Answer (score 2):

```js
const input = document.querySelector('.tax_obj')
console.log(input.value)
```

```html
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action="" class="try">
      <input type="text" class="tax_obj" value='[ {"taxid": 1, "taxname":
      "vat", "taxpercentage": 13, "sortorder": 1, "calculationmode": null }, {
      "taxid": 2, "taxname": "hst", "taxpercentage": 10, "sortorder": 2,
      "calculationmode": null }]'>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here, the issue is your use of the `""` and `''` symbols. If you are using `""` and you need to use another blockquote inside it, then you should use a single quote `''` to get things working.

Afterwords, you can use a querySelector to grab the class and console its value.

Answer (score 0):

Its looks like an array of object. This code may help you. If you want a specific object from this array. You can try value[0] or value[1]

```
    <input id="input" type="hidden" class="tax_obj"
            value='[{"
            taxid":1,"taxname":"vat","taxpercentage":13,"sortorder":1,"calculationmode":null},{"taxid":2,"taxname":"hst","taxpercentage":10,"sortorder":2,"calculationmode":null}]'>
        <script>
const value =JSON.parse(document.querySelector(".tax_obj").value);
            console.log(value);
        </script>
```

Comment: You need to use `JSON.parse()` to access it as an array.